# Algorithm to construct Fibonacci's tree with given minimum

Tags: algorithm, recursion, binary-tree, fibonacci

I want to make a Fibonacci tree but with a minimum number other than 1, and I can't seem to find anything about it.

Here's an example of a "normal" fibonacci tree, with the minimum node 1.

```
        5
      /   \
     3     7
   /   \  /
  2    4 6
 /
1
```

What I want to do is for example, with minimum 3:

**With height 0:** it would be the empty tree.

**With height 1:**

```
3
```

**With height 2:**

```
   4
  /
 3
```

**With height 3:**

```
     5
   /   \
  4     6
 /
3
```

**With height 4:**

```
         7
      /    \
     5      9
   /   \   /
  4    6  8 
 /
3
```

...And so on.

My problem is, I can't seem to see a pattern in it, so I can't think of an algorithm to write.

I know that the left subtree's height is `h-1` (where `h` is the original given height) and the right subtree's height is `h-2`. And I can't see how they calculate the root's number. But other than that, I'm really stuck.

Comment: In your first picture, what do numbers represent?

Comment: You seem not to ask how to construct a "normal" Fibonacci tree. Given that you know how to do that, just add `minimum - 1` to every number and you're done? E.g. with minimum 3: `3 - 1 = 2` ==> add `2` to each node in the "normal" Fibonacci tree. Or are you asking about how to construct a Fibonacci tree in general? Another requirement that you forgot ist that a Fibonacci tree is a special kind of an [AVL tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) which itself is a [binary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree). From that information you get a clue about the root.

Comment: @Michi I'm asking how to construct a Fibonacci tree with a given minimum and a given height. That minimum could be 1 or it could be any natural number (I'm kind of asking for a generalization of the Fibonacci tree?) I'll read about AVL trees, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the Fibonacci tree is a recursively defined structure, the easiest way is to think about a recursive algorithm.

This is some sort of C-style pseudo code (not covering any edge cases - I leave that to you as part of the exercise).

```c
function createTree(height)
{
  // basic cases
  if(height == 0) return NULL;
  if(height == 1)
  {
    node = new Node;
    node.numNodesInTree = 1;
  }
  else
  {
    // according to the definition of the fibonacci tree
    node = new Node;
    node.leftChild  = createTree(height - 1);
    node.rightChild = createTree(height - 2);
    node.numNodesInTree =   node.leftChild.numNodesInTree
                          + node.rightChild.numNodesInTree
                          + 1; // also count the current node
  }
  return node;
}
```

You end up with a tree that has the Fibonacci structure, but not the right numbers **yet**. As a little helper, you have the number of nodes for each sub tree.

Then you can do something like:

```c
function fillTree(offset, node, minimum) // offset means "all numbers in this subtree must be bigger than offset"
{
  // According to the binary search tree definition,
  // all numbers in the left sub tree have to be lower than
  // the current node.
  // All nodes in the right sub tree have to be larger.
  node.value =   node.leftChild.numNodesInTree // the number has to be bigger than all numbers in the left sub tree
               + 1                             // (that's the "one bigger")
               + offset                        // offset for right subtrees
               + minimum - 1;                  // Just stupidly add the minimum (as mentioned in the comment to your question)
  fillTree(offset, node.leftChild, minimum);      // propagate offset to left children
  fillTree(node.value, node.rightChild, minimum); // for the right sub tree, the current node's value is the new offset
                                                  // because all nodes in the right sub tree have to be bigger than the current node (binary search criterion)
}
```

Then you can call it like:

```c
root = createTree(height);
fillTree(0, root, 3); // when initially calling it, the offset is always 0
                      // You can set the minimum arbitrarily (i.e. 3 as in your example)
```

Since this is pseudo code, I obviously haven't tested it, but you could get the idea behind that.

Comment: Thank you soooooooooo much for taking the time to answer, you have no idea how helpful this was!!!